# Does the Firebase custom event limit affect data being to Google Analytics

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

When using the Firebase SDK for Firebase Analytics, if you exceed the 500 unique custom event limit in an app instance which then generates an [error code](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/errors). Can GTM still pass data to Google Analytics once the limit has been reached?

Comment: Can you confirm you want to send data to GA and Firebase?

Comment: Yes both but I accept that if the limit is reached the Firebase collection could be disrupted

Comment: The limit is on the naming only, not the number of times it's happened in the session. It doesn't affect GTM, though you should know GA mobile SDK is being sunset this year.